# Switch language and redirect to specific CMS page

Tags: cms, language

We have a language select page which the user gets presented with when they first enter the site, we want to redirect the user to the "/home" CMS page when they select a language.

I know that `$_lang->getCurrentUrl();` redirects to the current URL, and `$_lang->getHomeUrl();` redirects to the home page (which is currently this language select page) how can we get it to do the following `$_lang->getPageUrl("home");` as this snippet doesn't do the job.

Cheers, C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$_lang->getBaseUrl().'home';
```

If you want the secure url, you can get

```
$_lang->getBaseUrl('link', true).'home';
```

[UPDATE]
Or you can try this one:

```
$_lang->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'home'))
```

This way you have the `___store` param in GET and this ensures you get on the right website no mater how you configured your store urls.

Comment: Brilliant perfect solution with the update. Thank you